# Contar veces en que aparece un registro en Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo esta tabla mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la columna jornada tengo dos jornadas "po" y "20", lo que necesito es una consulta que me devuelva el número de jornadas que hay registradas que en este caso es 2.

Tengo esto:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM juego WHERE fecha = '2018-12-23' GROUP BY jornada
```

Comment: Por favor crea tu ejemplo aquí: http://sqlfiddle.com/ así sabremos exactamente tu estructura pues una imágen no nos es suficiente a muchos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, quite la agrupación y agregue el modificador distinct para contar los elementos distintos

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT jornada) AS total FROM juego WHERE fecha = '2018-12-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me parece que tu consulta esta bien iniciada, lo único es que en la función de agregación `COUNT()` en vez del comodín `*` pases directo el nombre de la columna que deseas contar

```
SELECT COUNT(jornada) AS Total
FROM juego 
GROUP BY fecha;
```

Ahora por la muestra de datos que colocas veo innecesario el uso de `WHERE fecha = ...` puesto que todos tus datos tienen la misma fecha

Comment: No funciona, me devuelve 5 y 4

Comment: @JorgeAlonso y si usas el campo fecha para agrupar?

Comment: no uso ese campo para agrupar